# How do I copy a file into my WAR classpath based on a command line argument?

Tags: gradle, build, classpath, environment

I’m using Gradle 2.7. I have the following files in my build"

```
src/main/environment/dev/aws.properties
src/main/environment/qa/aws.properties
src/main/environment/prod/aws.properties
```

How do I copy a file into my assembled WAR classpath based on whether someone specifies the environment on the command line when executing a build (e.g. gradle build `-Penv=qa`)?  If the `-Penv=xxx` flag isn't specified, I’d like the `src/main/environment/dev/aws.properties` file to be copied into the class path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be:

```
war {
   def env = project.hasProperty('env') ? project.env : 'dev'
   from("src/main/environment/$env") {
      include('aws.properties')
      into('WEB-INF/classes')
   }
}
```

If you need `env` elsewhere you can define it at the beginning of the script. If you have added `src/main/environment` to source sets it can be used instead of path.

Comment: THis code is copying the aws.properties file into the root of the WAR, alongside the WEB-INF and META-INF directories, but it is not getting picked up in teh classpath.  Wouldn't the file need to be in the WEB-INF/classes or WEB-INF/lib directory to be on the classpath?

Comment: What you need is to configure `into`.